# How to print version of ncurses from Perl

Tags: perl, ncurses

How can I print the version of the `ncurses` library? I use the `Curses` library from `Perl`. I do not care much about the version of the CTAN package which from what I understand is just the interface to access the curses library.

I downloaded the latest (unstable) version of `ncurses` from here:
http://invisible-island.net/datafiles/current/ncurses.tar.gz

I compiled it without error (with just `./configure` and `make`) but have not yet done `sudo make install`

I would like to know how to (1) check which version of curses is installed and eventually (2) switch between versions.

Note that I am on Ubuntu 13.04. Perhaps the following information is helpful:

```
$ locate ncurses.h
/usr/include/ncurses.h
$ locate curses.h
/usr/include/curses.h
/usr/include/ncurses.h
/usr/include/python2.7/py_curses.h
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that indeed there is no function in `Curses.pm` to get the current (n)curses version.
You can write a small C program to get the value:

```
/* compile with "cc -lcurses filename.c" */
#include <curses.h>
main() {
  printf("%s\n", curses_version());
}
```

On my system this prints `ncurses 5.7.20100313`.

But it would also be nice to have the curses_version() function also available from `Curses.pm` — maybe ask the Curses.pm author?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `ncurses5-config` (or `ncurses-config`, `ncurses4-config`, etc...) on your system? I for instance can do this on my CentOS 6 system:

```
$ ncurses5-config --version
5.7.20090207
```

which you could call from perl also:

```
my $ncurses_version = qx(ncurses5-config --version);
```

If you are working with different major versions, you might have to try a couple `ncurses*-config` commands, e.g.:

```
my $nc_version;
for my $nc (qw'ncurses-config ncurses5-config ncurses4-config') {
  no warnings 'exec';
  $nc_version = qx($nc --version) and last;
}
print "nc_version=$nc_version\n";
```

Hope this helps you,
 Christian

Comment: Thanks Christian, this does help!